# The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, silverlight, c#-4.0

Assign datetime value in code in silverlight and save it to db by domainservice and EF:
DateCreated = DateTime.Now

in database, the mapped column datetype is datetime, not datetime2.

then got following error:
The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678474/the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-ou)

Comment: figure it out. becuase more than one item for DateTime. And some of them not set value(null).

Answer (score 0):

In your model put a questionmark behind the datatype.

```
public DateTime? myDate {get; set;}
```

This will allow NULL to be written in the database.