# DateTime2 conversion Error in a DB with no DateTime2 Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am getting this error when I save my changes using EF:

> "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Funny thing is that I don't have ANY DateTime2 columns in my database.  (I just double checked using [this query](https://gist.github.com/1407385).)

I also did a solution wide search to see if the text DateTime2 is in there anywhere.  It comes up empty.

So, if my model does not have DateTime2 and my DB does not have DateTime2, why is EF converting from a DateTime2?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8043816/270591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was the answer to my question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708344/16241