# Two primarykeys on same table and foreignkey

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables that one of them relate to other. 
The first table

```
 public class Text
  {
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(7)]
    [MaxLength(7)]
    public string Fieldname { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Required]
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [MinLength(1)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

and the second table:

```
public class Language
  {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2), MinLength(2)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }
  }
```

The seed data looks as follow:

```
context.Language.AddOrUpdate(
        new Language() {Code = "DE", Country = "German"},
        new Language() {Code = "EN", Country = "English"});

context.Text.AddOrUpdate(
        new Text { Fieldname = "TEXT001", Description = "Server", Language = context.Language.First(e => e.Code == "EN") },
        new Text { Fieldname = "TEXT001", Description = "Server", Language = context.Language.First(e => e.Code == "DE") }
      );
```

I update the db and got following error message :

> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Texts'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Texts'. The duplicate key value is (TEXT001).

What is wrong?

Comment: Yes but in combination with fields `Fieldname` and `Language`.  Please look at the seed data, then you should what I mean.

Comment: @zero_coding - Not sure but I think you should specify that the `Language` `key` is a foreign key - `[Key, ForeignKey("Language"), Column(Order=2)]`

Comment: Is setting complex property `Language` as key valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@IvanStoev answer is correct. But I want to show another option. I suggest mapping your classes using Fluent API. Beleive me, this way, your models will remain much more cleaner and mappings are easy to understand.

*Text* model and mapping for it:

```
public class Text
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }  
    public string LanguageCode { getl set; } // Add this foriegn key property
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}

internal class TextMap
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<Text>
{
    public TextMap()
    {
        // Primary key
        this.HasKey(m => new { m.FieldName, m.LanguageCode });

        this.Property(m => m.FieldName)
                .HasMaxLength(7)
                .IsFixedLength();

        this.Property(m => m.LanguageCode)
                .HasMaxLength(2)
                .IsFixedLength();

        // Properties
        this.Property(m => m.Description)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);                      

        // Relationship mappings
        this.HasRequired(m => m.Language)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.LanguageCode)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

*Language* model and mapping for it:

```
public class Language
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

internal class LanguageMap
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<Language>
{
    public LanguageMap()
    {
        // Primary key
        this.HasKey(m => m.Code);

        this.Property(m => m.Code)
                .HasMaxLength(2)
                .IsFixedLength();

        // Proeprties
        this.Property(m => m.Country)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Then you should override `OnModelCreating` method of DbContext and add your mappings as:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TextMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LanguageMap());
}
```

Comment: So at the navigation property, I do not have to set `[Key]` anymore?

Comment: You have primary key at Navigation proeprty, but you do not use any of attributes if you use Fluent API @zero_coding

Comment: aha ok. I ill try it and let you know.

Comment: I did as you describe above, for example delete all attributes etc. When I do the `Update-Database` I've got following error `The object 'DF__Texts__Fieldname__21B6055D' is dependent on column 'Fieldname'`.

Comment: @zero_coding I renamed `Fieldname` to `FieldName`. May it be the reason of error?

Comment: Au sorry, I thought it is a mistake. Why do rename it?

Comment: @zero_coding You do not have to change it, I just renamed it for myself :). I am sorry but I haven't used UpdateDatabase too much. `DF__Texts__Fieldname__21B6055D` looks like auto-generated name of PK. But I do nor know exact reason of the error.

Comment: This help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460912/the-object-df-is-dependent-on-column-changing-int-to-double. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can define part of the PK with navigation property, so EF simply ignores your `Column` and `Key` attributes on `Language` property, ending up with PK being just `Fieldname`.

You need to include the FK field explicitly like this:

```
public class Text
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(7)]
    [MaxLength(7)]
    public string Fieldname { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2), MinLength(2)]
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LanguageCode")]
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [MinLength(1)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```