# Fluent API syntax to map DateTime properties to datetime2 columns for a specific table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I am adding few tables to an existing database using Entity Framework code first and fluent API.

After going through [SQL Server datetime2 vs datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime) and [Why You Should Never Use DATETIME Again!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/), I am mapping the DateTime properties to datetime2 using

```
mb.Entity<SomeClass>()
    .Property(q => q.DateTimeTypePropety)
    .HasColumnType("datetime2");
```

[Forcing Entity Framework to use datetime2 data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248488/force-entity-framework-5-to-use-datetime2-data-type) is not an option as it will affect existing tables.

```
 modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
    .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
```

Is there a fluent API syntax to do this for specific tables instead of mapping each property individually?

Thanks for your time.