# EF Specify Target MS SQL Version

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

We are using EntityFramework Version 5 and we are run MS SQL 2012 locally, but the particular project I'm on has MS SQL 2005 installed in production.

The reason and the current solution is provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678474/the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-o/4708344#4708344).

My question is if there is an annotation or something in that can be specified in a file that ISN'T regenerated every time that you update from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a DbConfiguration class, that includes a  call to SetManifestTokenResolver as in the sample here: http://romiller.com/2014/06/10/reducing-code-first-database-chatter/

And for EF 5 use this 
[How to configure ProviderManifestToken for EF Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741499/how-to-configure-providermanifesttoken-for-ef-code-first/12060518#12060518)

Comment: This seems to apply to EF6+?